# ASP.NET __doPostBack rendered after beginning or near end of form tag

Tags: javascript, asp.net, webforms, postback

I'm trying to manually call the ASP.NET (3.5) javascript postback function `__doPostBack` from my javascript code. The problem is that the postback script block, that is normally rendered right after the beginning of the `<form>` tag (and the hidden fields), is occasionally rendered near the closing `</form>` tag.

Is there any way to force it to be rendered near the beginning of the form tag? Also, how does ASP.NET decide when/where to render the postback client script block?

**Edit > Additional Info:**
The javascript code resides inside a user control that references the `__doPostBack` function. The control itself does not contain any 'postback controls' that would call that function. (When I mention 'postback controls', I mean ASP.net controls that call the `__doPostBack` function and not the asp.net `ImageButton` and `Button` controls)

Based on what I've observed and @Brian's comment on the dependency of the postback script on the availability of 'postback controls' on the page, I've found that when the page contains controls that cause postback, the __doPostBack script block is rendered after the opening `<form>` tag and when there are none, it renders them near the closing `</form>` tag (or according to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50579/dopostback-not-rendering-on-postback/50593#50593) it's not even supposed to be rendered). Now it would make sense for ASP.NET not to render the postback script if there are no controls that require it, but the apparent position of the script near the closing  tag is the one that still eludes me. I haven't been able to find any documentation that suggests this behavior. All I've been able to find was [this](http://weblogs.asp.net/yousefjadallah/archive/2010/06/27/insure-that-dopostback-function-implemented-on-the-page.aspx).

Having said that, I've found a couple ways around this issue:

1. Add a 'postback control' and set its visibility to hidden via css (not the Visible property). eg. `<asp:LinkButton ID="RequirePostBackScriptLink" runat="server" style="display:none;" />` (this is what I'm using)
2. Add the control to the [`Page.RegisterRequiresPostBack`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.page.registerrequirespostback.aspx) and implement the [`IPostBackDataHandler`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.ipostbackdatahandler.aspx) interface.

Finally, as @Jonathan_Bates mentioned in his post, the proper thing to do is to wrap the reference to `__doPostBack` inside a function that is an event handler to `load` (or `ready` if you're using jquery). That way, there wouldn't be a need to depend on the actual placement of the `__doPostBack` script.

It'd be great if anyone can provide more info on this, aforementioned, behavior.

Answer (score 2):

I am guessing that where it renders is important to you so that your scripts render after it and can invoke it (which let me say up front, is a bad idea to begin with).

You just need to make sure that whatever script you are using to call `__doPostBack` calls it after its been read into the browser. If you use a library like jQuery and its `$(document).ready()` convention, you can be sure that your code won't execute until all other code is loaded, and therefor your code would be able to call `__doPostBack`.

Comment: Wrapping the reference to the postback function in a handler function scope like you suggested by means of the jquery ready event would definitely be the proper route to take, but I'm trying to understand ASP.NET's logic behind rendering the default __doPostBack script block.

Answer (score 0):

Some of it is controlled by the controls that render, whereas the page injects the client script blocks and startup scripts at a pre-defined point...

I assume this is for a control or something?  This isn't for a standard  block?

Comment: Yes this is for a control that has a script that basically 'hijacks' the default __doPostBack function and then eventually calls the postback via a callback. 
But you are right, it is in a way dependent on whether there are any 'postback controls' (excluding the ImageButton and asp.net Button controls, since they use a regular submit and post back to the same page). What I've observed is that if the page does not have any 'postback controls' the script block is rendered near the closing form tag (or from what I've read, not rendered). I'm looking for documentation to validate this observation.